# Not getting data for the first time in recyclerview;

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, jsonparser

I have FB, Google and normal login in my app.when I log in with FB or google everything is fine, but whenever I signup from the app and sign in instantly I am not getting data in CartActivity RecyclerView, but data is showing in postman or browser.Again when I uninstall the app and reinstall data start showing that old login credentials.
CartActivity:

```
    try {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        // Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "responce"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("Response is : " + response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsono.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String total = object.getString("cart_total");

                                    jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");
                                    JSONArray jarray1 = object.getJSONArray("product_description");
                                    for (int j = 0; j < jarray1.length(); j++) {
                                        JSONObject object1 = jarray1.getJSONObject(j);

                                        JSONArray jarray2 = object1.getJSONArray("data");
                                        for (int k = 0; k < jarray2.length(); k++) {
                                            JSONObject object2 = jarray2.getJSONObject(k);
                                            String Name = object2.getString("product_name");
                                            String Image = object2.getString("product_image");
                                            String Price = object2.getString("product_price");
                                            String Qty = object2.getString("product_qty");
                                            String sku = object2.getString("product_sku");
                                            String ProId = object2.getString("product_id");
                                          System.out.println("VALUES: " + Name + "price" + Price + "qty" + Qty + sku + "proid" + ProId);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                rccart.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
                                cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("EXCPTION IN SUCCESS REQUEST : " + ex.toString());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        System.out.println("ERROR IN REQUEST : " + error.getMessage());
                    }

                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                90000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CartActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(CartActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }


}
```

Comment: remove the stringRequest.retry policy

Comment: it wont show after uninstalling that app

Comment: There are large data in cart that's why i am using stringRequest.setRetryPolicy. otherwise it'll not fetchdata

Comment: retry policy retries the request multiple times..it has nothing to do with large data

Comment: Try adding `rccart.setAdapter(cartAdapter);` where you initialize  `rccart` and `cartAdapter` and remove `rccart.setAdapter(cartAdapter);`  from the response.

Comment: @santanu Sur when i am removing setRetryPolicy, i am not getting any data

Comment: @sunil not working sir

Comment: Are you sure that you are not getting an exception ,ie `EXCPTION IN SUCCESS REQUEST :` in logcat. Also three nested `for` loops really required ?.

Comment: show your volley response for both scenarios of signup instant login and login through fb or others

Answer (score 0):

make one pojo class that define all the field if you getting at a response time like below code..

```
public class DataClass {
String Name ;
String Image ;
String Price ;
String Qty ;
String sku ;
String ProId;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}

public String getQty() {
    return Qty;
}

public void setQty(String qty) {
    Qty = qty;
}

public String getSku() {
    return sku;
}

public void setSku(String sku) {
    this.sku = sku;
}

public String getProId() {
    return ProId;
}

public void setProId(String proId) {
    ProId = proId;
}
```

}

Add list in recycler view adapter like ....

```
 private List<DataClass> mDataList=new ArrayList<>();

public CustomAdapter(List<DataClass> mDataList) {
    this.mDataList = mDataList;
}
```

then after get response data to add into array list and pass into adapter..

```
private List<DataClass> mListData=new ArrayList<>();// define in type-array in your pojo class name
  for (int k = 0; k < jarray2.length(); k++) {
        JSONObject object2 = jarray2.getJSONObject(k);
        DataClass dataClass=new DataClass();
        String Name = object2.getString("product_name");
        String Image = object2.getString("product_image");
        String Price = object2.getString("product_price");
        String Qty = object2.getString("product_qty");
        String sku = object2.getString("product_sku");
        String ProId = object2.getString("product_id");
        dataClass.setName(Name);
        dataClass.setImage(Image);
        dataClass.setPrice(Price);
        dataClass.setQty(Qty);
        dataClass.setSku(sku);
        dataClass.setProId(ProId);
        mListData.add(dataClass);
        System.out.println("VALUES: " + Name + "price" + Price + "qty" + Qty + sku + "proid" + ProId);
    }
    if (!mListData.isEmpty()){
        cartAdapter=new CartAdapter(mListData);
        rccart.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
        cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.That was happening because of cache. just cleared cache and problem solve.